# Flutter -Checkbox inside Listview

Tags: list, listview, flutter, checkbox

I'm having a problem with the checkbox in ListView..
The CHECK moves downward every time I added a new item in the list.. and If I delete an item, the check moves upward. I need some help guys. Thanks!
Please check the demo below.

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTPLr.gif)

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckboxListTile(
      title: const Text('Is Active'),
      value: checkedOrNot,
      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
        setState(() { 
            checkedOrNot = newValue
        });
      },
      secondary: const Icon(Icons.hourglass_empty),
    ),
```

or

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Text('Is Active', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Checkbox(
             value: checkedOrNot, //bool
             onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                     setState(() {
                    checkedOrNot = newValue;
                 });
                },
          )
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: My code is the same as yours. As you can see in the demo, there's a 3 checkbox and the checkbox in the middle is checked. So when I added a new item in the list, the check was moved downward. the check appears in the last checkbox even though the middle is the one that I checked.